# Clear cache after pressing f5

Tags: c#, asp.net-3.5

i am creating dynamic controls based on the dropdownlist selection and data available in the database. For this  i am using static variable. When we refresh the page using (f5,ctrl-f5,ctrl-r) value in the static varable remains. It creating problem.
How to clear the cache when the page is refresh.

Geetha

Comment: Can you explain a bit more? This much sounds like a question for superuser.

Comment: What Cache ? (some more chars)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume what you mean is that your server-side code is caching data and you want a client-side ctrl-F5 to clear your server-side cache?

In general this is a pretty bad idea - giving users the ability to purge your server-side caches will quickly cause performance issues.

If you really have to do this (and I sincerely recommend you don't) you could always look at the value of the request header `cache-control`. Browsers will set it to `no-cache` or `max-age=0` when you refresh manually from the browser. When you see that simply clear your server-side caches.

Comment: is there Anyother way to achieve this task?

Answer (score 1):

ctrl-f5 or ctrl-r

Comment: That's not going to work for this problem. It's not the clients cache he want to be purged.

Answer (score 1):

A static variable stays there until the class is recycled (i.e. when IIS will recycle).  If you want this to not be there on refresh then don't make it static.